# How to create another cloudfront distribution using same SSL certificates created in certificate manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

In Aws Certificate Manager, I have created SSL certificate and add it to dns.

```
*.test.example.com
```

In Cloudfront, I have created a distribution With below CNAME

```
dev.test.example.com
```

Then, I can successfully access dev.test.example.com.

After that, I try to create Another distribution with CNAME uat.test.example.com using the same SSL certificate

But error occurs and cannot create the distribution.

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CNAMEAlreadyExistsException: One or more aliases specified for the distribution includes an incorrectly configured DNS record that points to another CloudFront distribution. You must update the DNS record to correct the problem
```

Comment: I think for the second CNAME, you have to add it as `*.test.example.com` rather then `uat.test.example.com`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Can u explain for the reason? Because i already create SSL cert for *.test.example.com

Comment: In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions) in section "Duplicate and overlapping alternate domain names" they suggest it. Its possible it applies to your case?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use wildcards (`*`) in your DNS for cloudfront, just for the certificate. You should create a CNAME for each domain name and point it to its appropriate cloudfront url:

`dev.test.example.com` CNAME `0123456789.cloudfront.net`

`uat.test.example.com` CNAME `9876543210.cloudfront.net`

Having `*.test.example.com` is perfectly valid DNS, but means all traffic matching `*.test.example.com` (which would include your `dev`, `uat`, and any other future subdomains) will be sent to your dev cloudfront distribution.